# Flying pigs arrive

Tags: logical-deduction, cipher, pattern, visual

*You’ve built pens for flying pigs. Being, well, flying pigs, they pick their own accommodation in full accordance to their preferences. Can you figure out what creature joined them?*

[image]

- Pigs only occupy designated pens (marked with gray squares).
- There is a total of 7 pigs.
- The first pig arrived early and occupied the leftmost stall (as shown on the picture).
- Each fountain has exactly two pigs next to it:  one in a pen that is separated from the fountain by a wall, and one that is not.  Only vertically or horizontally adjacent pens are considered to be next to each other.
- Exactly two pigs are in completely enclosed areas.
- The pigs have a total of 18 walls adjacent to them. Walls shared by pigs are counted twice.

Comment: If a pig were in the pen to the left of the bottom fountain, would that count as completely enclosed and having 3 adjacent walls?

Comment: @DrXorile Yes, it would

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think this is how to place the pigs

> [image]

Deusovi mentioned correctly in the comments that determining the final answer has to do with

> [The Pigpen Cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigpen_cipher)

Furthermore, as determined by Luke Bickell in the comments, applying the logic that

> Pens with pigs should have dots and those which don't shouldn't.

The grid reads

> ELDER KIN BEHOLDER

Comment: I might be misunderstanding the problem, but doesn't the top fountain have 3 pigs in adjacent pens?

Comment: @DrXorile My interpretation is that we count the number of pigs adjacent to the fountain, not the number of pigs in pens adjacent.

Comment: Pig allocation correct!

Comment: The obvious way to get an answer out of this is rot13(gur cvtcra pvcure, ohg ab pubvpr bs qbgf frrzf gb cebivqr nalguvat hfrshy. Rira nantenzzvat, gur bayl HXNPQ jbeqf ner ovyyvba, oevpbyr, pbpxvre, pbeorvy, svpxyre, syvpxre, naq xrvyybe.)

Comment: @Deusovi You're on the right path, keep going

Comment: using this solution and rot13(cvtcra pvcure, V tbg 'xryqreva orubyqre', juvpu pbhyq znlor or genafyngrq (Qhgpu) nf 'snyyvat Orubyqre' (Orubyqre orvat n sylvat zbafgre)

Comment: @LukeBickell The letter ordering seems off a bit? No translation step should be necessary

Comment: rot13(ryqre xva orubyqre?) otherwise, I'm out of ideas

Comment: Aaah. Another dungeons & dragons reference...

Comment: @hexomino should be banned from asnwering :P he quickly answers most of the questions...

Comment: @SayedMohdAli Which is the reason behind spoilers...